# Learning OpenGL 1

Tags: opengl

I am studying computer science since 3 semester and we just started with openGl 1.0. We are doing the very basics (math behind the api).

The lecture is structured in 4 parts and goes 4 semester.

Now I really want to read a book while I am hearing this lecture but I am not sure which one I should read.

Should I get a book for opengl 1 or opengl 3+ ?

Or should I wait until we start with opengl3 and read in the meantime a book about math , something like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1435458869)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing wrong with an older version of OpenGL for learning 3D graphics. The C programming language is 40 years old, Lisp even more, but they're still relevant. I do think it's important that you use at least OpenGL 1.3 or maybe 2.0/2.1 because, like most software, OpenGL 1.0 had some horrible bits that were quickly fixed in later versions.

With OpenGL 1.x or 2.x you'll learn the fundamentals of 3D graphics: polygon geometry, nested transformations, lights & materials, texture mapping. And they're easier to learn with OpenGL 1 or 2 than with 3 or 4, because there is a lot more built-in functionality in OpenGL 1/2 and many years worth of books and online tutorials for guidance.

Books to read: the "Red Book" OpenGL Programming Guide, preferably an older 3rd or 4th edition; or the OpenGL SuperBible, again a 2nd or 3rd edition. You could also look up the excellent NeHe web tutorials - for OpenGL 1/2 these are now called "legacy tutorials." For the maths behind 3D graphics, I'd recommend the 3D Math Primer for Graphics and Game Development by Dunn & Parberry.

What you don't get in OpenGL 1.x are shaders for modern GPUs. Once you've got the basics down, you can start with vertex and fragment shaders in OpenGL 2. And once you're comfortable with those, start programming for OpenGL 4. (I recommend skipping over 3 and going straight to OpenGL 4 / DirectX 11.)

This is assuming you want to learn from the top down, starting with built-in API functions that do most of the work for you and gradually going into more detail. If instead you'd rather dive in to the deep end, you want the OpenGL SuperBible 5th edition and a modern GPU with OpenGL 4. This is not the approach I prefer because IMHO OpenGL 3/4 are "3D assembly languages" and the learning curve is very steep, but some people do prefer it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, it is a big difference. Today all realtime graphics happens on freely programmable GPUs. You can't really compare this to programming languages. Or actually you can. C is as good as 40 years ago, because it's Turing Complete. OpenGL-3 with GLSL is Turing Complete as well. But fixed function OpenGL-1 is *not* Turing Complete. And because this is a huge conceptual difference. Also shaders have been an integral concept in computer graphics for a long time, but fixed function pipelines GPUs (like OpenGL-1.1) never supported this; a lot of graphics coders were sneering at GPUs due to that.

Comment: Also I think that doing it with shaders makes learning easier. Yes, there is more boilerplate code to be written. But the mere fact that no "magic" is going behind the scenes actually enhances the learning experience. And many of the newbie pitfalls of fixed function OpenGL (like the ill practice of setting up projection in a event handler) are simply not there in OpenGL-3. Also the whole hassle with glTexEnv and which texturing targets to enable/disable disappear.

Comment: Today I bought the redbook 8th edition for version 4.3 (rough cuts). I will read it simultaneously to my lecture.

Comment: @datenwolf I just need to draw a triangle, I am a beginner, using GLUT is like ~10 lines of code, using GLSL is like ~40, evidently, using Immediate Mode (Fixed Function Pipeline) is a lot easier than Shaders.

Comment: @Ivanzinho: Yes, a simple "Hello Triangle" looks more complicated using the modern APIs. However the further you move away from those simple things into more advanced stuff, the more clunky and cumbersome the old APIs become.

Comment: @datenwolf I'm suspecting that it doesn't hurt too much to learn the old and new approach, I'm thinking it's actually mandatory since you can prototype things quickly in the old fashion and then make them scalable as in the new fashion. I've seen Bisqwit (who is a somewhat skilled programmer) prototyping in QuickBasic and then writing the program in C, so, in other words, because the motorcycle was invented doesn't mean the bycicle is clunky or cumbersome.

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL-1.0 – wow that's over 20 years old. Or do you mean OpenGL-1.1, still over 15 years old. Anyway, please tell your professor or teaching assistant to teach something usefull in the future; you're probably not in a computer graphics palentology course.

You should definitely learn OpenGL-3 and further. Version 3 did introduce long overdue API cleanups and the requirement of having to use shaders for everything makes things easier in the long run, actually.

Comment: I am studying something unique, it is computer science with the focus on computer graphics. I am not entirely sure which version we are using but he told us that we start with opengl 1. We are only using glut at the moment. So learning opengl 3+ would also help me to understand opengl1? Because I still have to write my exam in opengl1/glut.

Comment: @MaikKlein: OpenGL-3 is very different from OpenGL-1.1; there's no immediate mode, no built in matrix stack, everything happens through buffer objects. So learning OpenGL-3 will not help you with OpenGL-1. But like I said, a computer graphics course given *today* should not use OpenGL-1 at all.

Comment: I guess then the pipeline that we are learning is opengl 1.1 too? `Object coordinates -> modelview matrix -> projection matrix -> perspective division -> viewport transformation `

Comment: The basic theory is the same. Older GL versions hide a lot of the action and do things in old and inefficient ways. If the goal is mainly to learn about matrix and vector math it should be sufficient, but you will not learn much about modern ways of doing things.

Comment: I think the main reason why they are using older GL version is that is easy to set up for anyone with almost any hardware. To require everyone to have laptops with hardware supporting GL3+ is not always realistic. This also applies to computer labs at the school.